# change tr background color dynamically

Tags: javascript, mysql, servlets

I have made one simulator in which, through file reader data read from text file and inserted each line in database as records. also data is successfully viewed through select query in jsp page. now I want to display each row with different color based on severity. if I insert record menually in mysql table then there is no problem. bt if data inserted by simulator then that data even not allowing to comapare with string...plz plz help me..

code:

```
package file_mgt;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;





/**
* Servlet implementation class File_mgt
*/
@WebServlet("/File_mgt")
public class File_mgt extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */


public File_mgt() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)     throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 3);
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
 String alarm_name="";
 String alarm_severity="";
 String  alarm_desc="";
 Date time;


BufferedReader br = null;
Random rand = new Random();
int Tlines=0;
int minimum=1;
int maximum=10;
String sCurrentLine = null;
String line1 = null;
int counter=0; 

ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
Connection conn=null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;


try {
    response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 7);

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //open connection
    conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb","root","root");
    out.println("successfully connected!!!! :");


    out.println("hi");
    //String fileName = "D:/workSpace/Filemgt/src/files/test.txt";



    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/workSpace/Filemgt/src/files/test.txt"));



    //========== total numbers of lines in file

    while (br.readLine() != null) {
        Tlines++;
    }
    out.println("total number of lines:"+Tlines);


    //================generate random number======

    Random rn = new Random();
    int range = maximum - minimum + 1;
    int randomNum =  rn.nextInt(range) + minimum;
    out.println("random number:"+randomNum);

    //=============

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/workSpace/Filemgt/src/files/test.txt"));
    //line1 = br.readLine();

    //out.println(line1);

    while ((line1 = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //out.println(sCurrentLine);
        counter++;

        if(counter == randomNum){

            //out.println(line1);

             String[] splited = line1.split(",");
               alarm_name=splited[0];
               alarm_severity=splited[1];
               alarm_desc=splited[2];



            Insertion(conn,pst,alarm_name,alarm_severity,alarm_desc);
                   out.println("\n");
                out.println(alarm_name);
                out.println(alarm_severity);
                out.println(alarm_desc);

        }







    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    out.println(e);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    out.println(e);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    out.println(e);
} finally {

    if (pst != null) {
        try {
            pst.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) { /* ignored */}
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) { /* ignored */}
    }
}



}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}



public static void Insertion(Connection conn, PreparedStatement pst, String alarm_name , String alarm_severity, String alarm_desc) throws SQLException{

    java.util.Date date = new Date();
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    //pst.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);

    pst=conn.prepareStatement("insert into test_alams2(name, severrity, description,Time) values(?,?,?,?)");
    pst.setString(1, alarm_name);
    pst.setString(2, alarm_severity);
    pst.setString(3, alarm_desc);
    pst.setTimestamp(4, timestamp);
    pst.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("inserted....");


}

}
```

above is my simulator... throught which data is inserted successfully.

data retrieve code is:

```
st=conn.createStatement();
String sql="select * from alarms2";

rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

  while(rs.next())

  {
      alarm_id=rs.getInt("id");
      alarm_name=rs.getString("Alarm_name");
        alarm_severity=rs.getString("Alarm_severity");
        alarm_desc=rs.getString("Alarm_desc");
        time=rs.getString("Time");




        out.println("<tr>");
    %>

   <td><a href="table_represent.jsp?id=<%= rs.getString("id") %>" ><%= alarm_id %></a></td>


        <%
        out.println("<td>"+alarm_name+"</td>");
         out.println("<td>"+alarm_severity+"</td>");
         out.println("<td>"+alarm_desc+"</td>");
         out.println("<td>"+time+"</td>");
        //out.println("<td>"+"its major"+"</td>");
         out.println("</tr>");
        // out.println(" <br> ");
         //out.println("\n Severity:"+alarm_severity);


        /* 
        if(alarm_severity.equalsIgnoreCase(Critical))
         {
         out.println(" <br> ");
             out.println("<h1>"+"its true"+"</h1>");
         }else {
            out.println(" <br> ");
             out.println(" => its not working");
         }
*/
         }  



 }
catch(Exception e){
out.println(e);
 }
```

now through javascript want to change tr background color of tr and the code is:

```
<script language="javascript">
  var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl-1");

 if (tbl != null) {
     for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
         for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++){

            if(tbl.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML == "major")
                tbl.rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "#fff000";

            else if(tbl.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML == "minor")
                tbl.rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "#000fff";
     }
 }

 }else document.writeln("Sorry");


</script>
```

bt there is problem in comparison...I can't do anything on record which is inserted by simulator. is there any solution???
plz help me.

Comment: Nobody has a time to read your huge code you have provided , kindly be precise what you want !

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of "major" or "minor"

`<script language="javascript">`

`var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl-1");`

`if (tbl != null) {`

`for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {`

`if (i%2==0)`

`tbl.rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "#fff000";`

`else`

`tbl.rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "#000fff";`

`}`

`else`

`document.writeln("Sorry");`

`</script>`

Hope this helps

Comment: I think your javascript is called before event the table is made and you are getting the error. You can put your javascript code in a function and call that function once the table has been created. In case you dont understand what I have said then let me know I shalll provide you with the sample code too.